# sort and retrieve items from a list in python

Tags: python, list

consider the following list:

```
alist = [[1, 'AAA0'], [2, 'AAAA1'], [3, 'BB2BB2'], [4, 'A3A3'], [5, 'A3A3']]
```

then if I want to sort the list according to the 2nd slot but at the same time get only the items that have 'A' inside I use:

```
 from operator import itemgetter
 print str([pt for pt in sorted(alist, key=itemgetter(1)) if 'A' in pt[1]])
```

my question is how after sorting them alphabetically, how do I group them by string length first and then group the ones that are the same. Like being able to retrieve the 2 'A3A3' only.

the

```
if 'A' in pt[1]
```

is returning all items that contain 'A' not the ones with 1 'A'.

so how do I group those with 1 'A', those with 2 'A' etc?

Comment: Tried this: - `if pt[1].count('A') == 1`?

Comment: @PavAmetvic.. So, were you able to work that out with it?

Comment: to separate by count yes,  right now trying to figure out how to group them by the count, but it seems Lev below has figured it out. You guys are fast !

Comment: @PavAmetvic.. Yeah, he has given you exactly what you need. Do remember to mark his answer as accepted by clicking the arrow besides the answer.

Comment: ok I did. other answers seem to disappear though, is that possible after time?

Comment: @PavAmetvic.. That was my answer. As it now seems not needed, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group elements of an iterable by custom key function with [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [1]: from itertools import groupby
In [2]: alist = [[1, 'AAA0'], [2, 'AAAA1'], [3, 'BB2BB2'],
   ...: [4, 'A3A3'], [5, 'A3A3']]
In [3]: key = lambda x: x[1].count('A')
In [4]: for k, g in groupby(sorted(alist, key=key), key=key):
    print k, tuple(g)
   ...:     
0 ([3, 'BB2BB2'],)
2 ([4, 'A3A3'], [5, 'A3A3'])
3 ([1, 'AAA0'],)
4 ([2, 'AAAA1'],)
```

Comment: hi Lev, thanks for your reply. I don't understand quite 'lambda' but I'll read more into it, seems like a one-time simple function.

Comment: @PavAmetvic Exactly, just saved some space. Could have written `def key(x): return x[1].count('A')`. The coolest thing about lambdas is that you can define them without giving them any name, but here I needed to use it 2 times, so I assigned it to a variable ( = defined a usual named function).

Comment: one more quick question:
what is the correct syntax if I wanted to group them also by count of 'A's and then the count of 'B's and the count of integers (numbers)?

something like -----> x[1].count('A','B') ?

Comment: @PavAmetvic No, it's not that simple. `count` doesn't know that you are using it as a key for `groupby` :) If you want groups inside groups, then you need to use `groupby` on each group returned by `groupby`, in a nested loop. If there are going to be multiple levels of nesting, you can put together a recursive function.

Comment: ok. it's going to be a long night...! will post something more developed back here tomorrow for feedback. Thanks

Comment: @PavAmetvic Good luck :) You can drop a comment here if you'd like to draw my attention to a new question of yours. Although I'm sure there will be enough people able to help right away.